# Are Web Services vulnerable to CSRF?

Tags: android, csrf, web-service

I'm testing an android application, it uses web services for every action, so I saw the requests don't have tokens or another anti-automation mechanism, they just need to validate a token to identify the session, then how could I test a CSRF attack to an android application with web services?

Comment: Have you reviewed https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)

Comment: I have completed my test, I could build a Web Service request with AJAX and JavaScript, this link helped me so much: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-wsajax/

Answer (score 1):

CSRF is an acronym used for Cross Site Request Forgery. It is an attack where a malicious website can transmit specially-crafted data to the vulnerable application on behalf of the victim, causing the state change in victim's account.

For the better understanding of the question for Android applications we can call it as Cross Application Request Forgery and for existence of this issue in mobile applications one application has to induce the state change for the other application installed on the device. Android supports the beautiful concept of **application sandbox** such that in the normal scenario one application can not access the data of any other application.

For successful execution of CSRF the session identifier(session cookie/session token) must be sent as the part of HTTP request for performing the state changing actions(*which is the default behaviour in web browsers*), it is highly unlikely to perform this kind of attack in Android applications since the attacking application won't be able to access the session identifier stored in vulnerable application sandbox to complete the attack.